# Angular 8 nested ngFor - click event affects all other items

Tags: angular, angular8

I have an image gallery. first it iterates over one main looks displaying details about events, then it iterates over a nested ngfor to display photos. It works perfectly, the only issue is that the UI shows the parent ngfor that is preceeding this main "activated" one - so when the user is iterating through the active parent ngfor's child ngfor gallery you can see the images moving in the gallery that is behind it.

Is it possible just to iterate over 1 ngfor child ngfor at a time without affecting all the other items in the parent array. essentially i need them all to be independently controlled and clickable without executing the same click events on the subsequent items.

```
<div *ngFor="let c of cards | async; let i=index" >
    <div>
        <img 
            [ngClass]=" ( currentActive() == x ) ? 'active' : 'disabled' "
            *ngFor="let h of c.album;  let x=index"
            [src]="h"
            [attr.data-img]="x"
            (click)="togglePhotos(x, c.album.length)" />        
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: why are you using `*ngFor="let h of c.album;  let x=index"` in the img tag? you're already using the same on its parent div.

Comment: You are correct! that was a mistake as its pseudo code. I have corrected it now

Comment: in togglePhotos try sending `h.length` instead of `c.album.length`

Comment: It would be nice if you show your typescript code as well.

Comment: Have you found any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 (click)="togglePhotos(x, c.album.length);$event.stopPropagation()"
```

Use click event like above to prevent the event bubbling.

you can find more on this [here](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

Comment: Thats not working im afraid. the subsequent items are still toggling

Comment: can you add (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" to your parent as well.

Comment: let me know the outcome

Comment: Still doesnt affect it sir